# Is there anyway to change ComboBox key inputs in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a combobox in my Userform. Whilst this is in focus, I am wanting to use the keyboard for WASD controls. However, I find that when I press WASD the Combobox is bringing up values beginning with these letters. Also, the arrow keys are cycling through the options as well.

Is there anyway to restrict these commands?

I have tried

```
Tool.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
```

This does not stop is doing this. Does anybody have any clue how I could access more specific controls to stop this kind of autofill happening?

Comment: What does *use the keyboard for WASD controls* mean? What are these keys supposed to control? Cannot you move the Focus? Do you have focusable Controls in that Form? What is this application about? What are you trying to *move*?

Comment: Think you're going to have to handle the keyPress event, detect if WASD and then move to the appropriate item in the backing list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only the Combobox control in your form and no other input controls, such as textbox, you can try the following code:

Please set `e.Handled = True` in the KeyPress event of the Combobox.

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

If you have some input controls, you want to retain the editing function, and you want to not interfere with the KeyPress event of the form.

You could refer to the following steps.
(1) Please set `Me.KeyPreview = False` in the `KeyDown` event of each input control.
(2) Please set `e.Handled = True` in the KeyPress event of ComboBox1.
(3) When double-clicking the form to enter WASD, you can set `ComboBox1.Focus()`.

Sample code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress      
    'edit  your code
    Dim offset As Integer = 10
    If e.KeyChar = "a" Then
        PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Location.X - offset, PictureBox1.Location.Y)
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "w" Then
        PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Location.X, PictureBox1.Location.Y - offset)
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "s" Then
        PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Location.X, PictureBox1.Location.Y + offset)
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "d" Then
        PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Location.X + offset, PictureBox1.Location.Y)
    End If
    e.Handled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.DoubleClick
    ComboBox1.Focus()
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = True
End Sub   

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    Me.KeyPreview = False
End Sub

End Class
```

Result:

[image]